# Replace values in a column based on a condition in Azure ML Studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

How do I replace the values in a specific column with a particular value based on a condition in Azure ML Studio. I can do this using pandas in python as foolows:

```
df.loc[df['col_name'] > 1990, 'col_name'] = 1
```

I'm trying to find a Module in Azure Machine Learning Studio that does the equivalent of this.

I understand there is a replace option under the ConverToDataset module and a Replace Discrete Values module. But neither of these seems to do what I want. Is there an option to replace the values in just one column to a specific value based on a condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the more general [Apply SQL Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/apply-sql-transformation), or the dedicated [Clip Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/clip-values) module. If all else fails, there's also [Execute Python Script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/execute-python-script).

Personally, for your example I'd use `Clip Values` with `Clip Peaks` and `Upper Threshold` set. For more complex rules I'd use either `Apply SQL Transformation` or `Execute Python Script`, depending on the rules but favouring SQL :).

Answer (score 0):

maybe using [Preprocess Text](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/studio-module-reference/preprocess-text) module will solve issue? 
I would recommend unchecking all the options and perform custom find-and-replace operations using regular expressions.

[image]